# Odoo 16 solution to add a day through automated action

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-16, time-and-attendance

[Odoo 16 Attendance App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCL60.jpg)

Is there a method to add a day automatically via scheduled actions if no clocking transactions are recorded against an employee? The clock in and out time should be 00:00:00. I want to add it via Python code (still a newbie to Python). If you can supply the Python code, it would be appreciated.

I've tried searching on Google, in Odoo, on Python websites but to no avail.